# "TFileOpenDialog requires Windows Vista or later"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have tried to use the new TFileOpenDialog and now my application is not compatible with Windows XP anymore. I find out that TFileOpenDialog only works on Vista and 7. It seems that TFileOpenDialogand does not check if it is running under Win XP in order to automatically and silently downgrade to TOpenFileDialog. Instead it just shows an error message. There is something I am missing? There is a wrapper that offers this functionality or I have to switch back to the classic TOpenFileDialog?

I don't understand why Embarcadero had to toss Borland's help system and build a new one (much worst) from zero.

Comment: You are wrong, they didnt rebuild documentation from zero. I have strong evidence with same sloppy code samples copypasted from D7 to D210.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TOpenDialog` and set `UseLatestCommonDialogs` to `true`. You don't get the new (Vista and up) properties (like `OkButtonLabel`) but at least the look and feel will be fine from a user's POV...

Comment: I guess I can programmatically set the UseLatestCommonDialogs to true or false based on OS version. Right?

Comment: Yeah but I would just set it to true - it picks the right CommonDialog itself at runtime AFAIK...

Comment: `UseLatestCommonDialogs` defaults to `True`. No need to do anything to it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan don't have the IDE available on this system... Thanks :-)

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. You have been really helpful. I cannot say the same about Embarcadero's new Help system.

Comment: THey are pretty good about improving the help; Contribute comments to their docwiki and those areas usually get better.  I wish they let you edit the wiki, and trusted the wiki concept (with reviews obviously) but at least they have a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called `TOpenDialog`.